# how to add cocoapods to an exsisting project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I have a project written in Objective-C with libraries. Is it possible to migrate this project to CocoaPods? If yes, please explain how to do this?

Comment: you should read this guide: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add CocoaPods to the project usual way. Add your existing libraries to the project using Podfile as well. Then once you update pods , all the libraries will be available in your project under the Pods. Now you can safely delete previous libraries from your project if you had copied them into your project.

Comment: Yeah, step by step, one dependency at a time is the best option.

Comment: I added CocoaPods to my existing project..And I first added the parse.framework but I couldn't add other libraries like AudioToolboxFramework,CFNetwork.framework,MobileCoreServices.Framework,QuartzCore.framework,Security.framework,StoreKit.framework,SystemConfiguratinon.framework,Accounts.framework,Social.framework,AdSupport.framework,CoreLocation.framework,CoreBluetooth.framework,Foundation.framework,CoreGraphics.framework

Comment: why couldn't you add them?

Comment: I tried to add them,but error occurring.I dont know the exact syntax..will you please help me?

Comment: Those frameworks you've mentioned probably have no relation to CocoaPods. If you've been already using those in previous version(before adding cocoapods), probably they are still in the project. No need to add again. Weren't you able to compile the project after adding Pods?

Comment: I compiled the project and I got errors : " The file “Pods-Shag iBeacon-Bolts-Private.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/Nexegen/Desktop/ShagGallery/shag_working_copy/shag-ibeacon/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Shag iBeacon-Bolts/Pods-Shag iBeacon-Bolts-Private.xcconfig) "